# Find Max from each column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

How to get max value from data frame using pandas?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [0,1,3,2,0,1],'two' : [0,5,1,0,1,1]})
```

I am using:

```
df1 = df.max()
```

This gives correct output but the data frame format is changed

I want to retain the original format of dataframe as below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [3],'two' : [5]})
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***option 1***
*`pandas` with `to_frame` and `transpose`*

```
df.max().to_frame().T
# pd.DataFrame(df.max()).T

   one  two
0    3    5
```

***option 2***
*`numpy` with `[None, :]` and `pd.DataFrame` constructor*

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.max(0)[None, :], columns=df.columns)

   one  two
0    3    5
```